# Flutter - routing to a specific screen when app launched through a push notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've built an app that sends push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Each notification contains data with a user ID, which I want to present a screen using it (for example, presenting the user's profile using the user ID).

I've tried this code:

```
//NotificationsHandler - a handler for push notifications
class NotificationsHandler {
  static final NotificationsHandler instance = NotificationsHandler();

  final _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();

  //Alot of of other functions including permission handling etc.
  
  void onBackgroundNotificationRecevied({Function onReceived}) {
    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: onReceived,
      onResume: onReceived,
      onLaunch: onReceived,
    );
  }
}

//MyMainScreen's initState
@override
  void initState() {
    NotificationsHandler.instance.onBackgroundNotificationRecevied(
      onReceived: (message) async {
        final secondScreenUserId = message['data']['userId'];

        await Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondScreen(
              secondScreenUserId,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
    super.initState();
  }
```

For some reason, when launching the app through the push notification (in both iOS and Android), the first screen (`MyMainScreen`) does not push the second screen (the `MyMainScreen` is presented).

Does anyone know why the code above doesn't work? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The background handler function be a high-level function, which means you have to delar it outside of the NotificationHandler class you have. Also, you can't have context in backgroundHandler.

Refer to https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/ for more on how to handle push notifications.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).